How to avoid definition of too many duplicate properties doing all the same thing on numpy arrays?
I have several classes for which i have defined some proprties doing their own stuff and returning a numpy ndarray:
def lin2db(x)
    return 10*np.log10(x)

class Example:
    ...

    @property
    def snr(self):
        # compute snr
        return ndarray(snr)
    
    @property
    def eta(self):
        # compute eta
        return ndarray(eta)
    
    ...

For each of these proprties i have another one defined to returned the standard value transformed in decibels cause i would like to avoid explicitly trasform the base properties when i use them and it is much more comfortable to just add '_db' in the attribute name when called:
@property
def snr_db(self):
    return lin2db(self.snr)

@property
def eta_db(self):
    return lin2db(self.snr)

...

However, this leads to prliferation of properties in my classes basivally doing always the same thing, which confuses a lot my code.
Is there a more concise way to retain teh same ieasyness in getting the original properties and the transformed one avoiding populating with so many properties definitioons?
I was thinking of extending the ndarray class / defining a wrapper class holding the ndarray and defining a db method doing the transformation so that i could do:
x = Thing()
x.snr     # returns snr
x.snr.db  # returns snr_db

but I would prefer to manage pure ndarrays, not extended classes or wrapper classes as the latter solution especially amy complicate the array manipulation. Is there a way to achieve my expected behaviour?

In a situation like this, you can have the property return a callable object.  Which makes it look like a standard method. This will change the API you are writing from:
x = Thing()
x.snr     # returns snr
x.snr.db  # returns snr_db

to
x = Thing()
x.snr()     # returns snr
x.snr.db()  # returns snr_db

Assuming you are storing the values in the Example class, you could use something like (in this example I am just converting the values to an array:
class SNR:
    def __init__(self, parent: object):
        self._parent = parent

    def __call__(self):
        return np.array(self._parent.values)

    def db(self):
        return 10*np.log10(self.__call__())


class Example:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = values

    @property
    def snr(self):
        return SNR(self)

Usage:
>>> e = Example([1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 1.1])
>>> e.snr()
array([1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 1.2, 1.1])
>>> e.snr.db():
array([0.79181246, 1.13943352, 0.79181246, 0.79181246, 0.41392685])


What about using a custom __getattr__ to detect the _db suffix and wrap the property with lin2db?
class Example:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.values = np.array(values)

    def lin2db(self, x):
        return 10*np.log10(x)
    
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr.endswith('_db'):
            return self.lin2db(getattr(self, attr.removesuffix('_db')))
        else:
            raise AttributeError
    
    @property
    def snr(self):
        # compute snr
        return self.values+1
    
    @property
    def eta(self):
        # compute eta
        return self.values+2

Example:
ex = Example([1, 2, 3])

ex.snr
# array([2, 3, 4])

ex.eta
# array([3, 4, 5])

ex.snr_db
# array([3.01029996, 4.77121255, 6.02059991])

ex.eta_db
# array([4.77121255, 6.02059991, 6.98970004])

